# Google Sheets: How to call built-in functions from within custom functions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, how can I call a built-in function (like [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) or [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)) from within a custom function (in Google App Scripts)?

Here's a trivial example that doesn't work:

```
function vlookupPassthrough(searchKey, range, index, is_sorted=false) {
  return VLOOKUP(searchKey, range, index, is_sorted);
}
```

There is no [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) function that's accessible from within the JavaScript, but it's a built-in function that's callable from the spreadsheet formulas.

Comment: Sorry you can't.  However VLOOKUP is easy to duplicate in javascript.

Comment: How could they be so stupid to not implement that from the beginning?

Comment: I find Google App Script and its relationship with Google Spreadsheet, Doc, GMail etc. to be an excellent development environment.  I've never felt it lacked for anything.

Comment: Here are the [Spreadsheet Service available to Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced).

Comment: @Neil Because those functions are not AppScript functions. they don't have even similar architecture so it's good they do not include them.

Comment: Have you considered using [named functions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534)?